# Finding the Shear Center for a Beam with 1 Axis of Symmetry

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stresses, solid-mechanics, bending

[image: Problem]

[image: Solution 1]

[image: Solution 2]

[image: Shared Solution]

I am trying to solve this problem of finding the shear center for the given beam and I have found that e = 35.94 mm, however the solution that was shared with me, had the answer of 39.17 mm.

My method is to integrate the segment for each force from 0 to l, which is the length of the segment, however in the solution that was shared with me the integration for the segment is from 80 to 120 mm, which does not make sense as the the integration of q dl, is for the segment's length.

Now obviously I integrate from 0 to 40, for a total of 40 mm length but the other solution integrates from 80 to 120 mm which is also 40 mm but there integration will definitely lead to different answer and so there is ambiguity as to which method should be followed.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for showing your work